# Acer Aspire S3 wireless issue

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

After a Windows 8 update my wireless stopped working. No wireless networks are detected anymore.

I tried to enable/disable the wireless device. uninstall it from device manager and install it again, update the wireless driver to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the Windows update the wireless driver stopped working. But it's not enough to update the driver for the wireless device, you should also update the BIOS to the latest version.

The drivers can be downloaded [here](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers).